# MySQL 5.7 Windows, table key issue?

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error, mysql-error-1064, ddl

What is wrong with this MySQL table script code?:

```
CREATE TABLE `securities_master`.`symbol` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `exchange_id` INT NULL,
  `ticker` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  `instrument` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `sector` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `currency` VARCHAR(32) NULL,
  `created_date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `last_updated_date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`), FOREIGN KEY 'index_exchange_id' ('exchange_id'))
ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

I think it is the "FOREIGN KEY" but I am not sure

Comment: You seem to be missing the REFERENCES part of adding a foreign key. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single quotes denote string literals in SQL. Object names (such as the constraint name and the columns it refers to) should be denoted with backticks, or nothing at all:

```
CREATE TABLE `securities_master`.`symbol` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `exchange_id` INT NULL,
  `ticker` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  `instrument` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `sector` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `currency` VARCHAR(32) NULL,
  `created_date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `last_updated_date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`), 
  FOREIGN KEY `index_exchange_id` (`exchange_id`)
  -- Here ----^-----------------^--^-----------^
)
ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

Comment: I tried that but it did not work, any other suggestions?